# Minimum logical application size

Tags: xamarin.android

I opened a new app and didn't add anything and when I archive the size is 10 mb.
There are complete applications and their size does not exceed 4 mb
Is this logical the size of an application that does not have any data. What is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce your app size, we can improve the things below to shrink our APK size.

- Fast our app loads.
- Much memory our app uses.
- Much power our app
  consumes.
- And much more.

For more details, please check the blog. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/shrinking-android-app-size/